# inserting state at specific line using sed

Tags: linux, bash, sed, awk

I have the following on my bash

```
DOMAIN=myserver
sed -i '34 d' $PATH
sed -i -e '34i$smtpServerAddress      = '${DOMAIN}.com';   '\' $PATH
```

result is:

```
$smtpServerAddress      = myserver.com;   '
```

but I'd like to have:

```
$smtpServerAddress      = 'myserver.com';
```

what's wrong?

Thanks

Comment: do you see the problem with the quotes? syntax highlight is your friend.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No need of two `sed`. You can make it as one like this.

```
sed -i.bak "34s/.*/\$smtpServerAddress      = '${DOMAIN}.com';/g"  $PATH
```

**(OR)**

As per your `sed`,

```
sed -i.bak "34i\$smtpServerAddress      = '${DOMAIN}.com';"  $PATH
```